# Timeout on task cancellation

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Consider this code:

```py
import asyncio
from async_timeout import timeout


async def sleep_coroutine(sleep=10):
    while True:
        print("Coroutine running")
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
        except Exception:
            print("Ignoring exception")


async def main():
    task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(sleep_coroutine())
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

    print("Cancelling")
    task.cancel()

    with timeout(3) as cancel_timeout:
        await task

    if cancel_timeout.expired:
        print("Timed out !")

    print("Finally done !")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

There is clearly an issue in this code, making task cancellation impossible. When `task.cancel()` is called, `sleep_coroutine` catches the `CancelledError` as any other `Exception`. So it ignores it and `await task` becomes infinite.
The broad except should be removed, or at least `asyncio.CancelledError` should be caught and re-raised before. But let's say I don't have hands on this code.

Is there a way to put a timeout on the task cancellation ? Something like "Wait for cancellation for 3 seconds with a timeout. And if timed out, 'force cancel' it".
Using `async_timeout` here doesn't help since it uses the same task cancellation internally.

Comment: It would help if you specified what this code produces, otherwise we're somewhat left to guess what "there is clearly an issue" means exactly.

Comment: If the task refuses to be cancelled, you can still simply *not `await`* it, which causes  it to not be further evaluated.

Comment: Explicited what the code does.  
About your second comment, I do want to make sure that the task has ended. My goal is to stop it. I do think that there is no solution without modifying the coroutine. But I'm asking in case anyone has any other solution.

Comment: you can always stop the eventloop, forcing all coroutines to be cancelled ..... or rather abruptly terminated.

Comment: True, but the use case is in a greater system where multiple tasks must be handled independently, without having the eventloop shut down

Comment: run each "risky" eventloop on a different thread ? you are running out of options here ... just edit the original code and remove the broad except ... you can always go lower level and manually remove the task from the loop, but that's more risky than stopping the loop.

Comment: That's exactly what I think. I just wanted to know if there was any other option I didn't know of. Thanks